# How i can add more condition to mysql query?

Tags: mysql

Table name is Sample

```
id name   status date 
1 ddd     1 2015-03-11 
2 dddd    1 2015-03-12 
3 dfdfgfg 0 2015-03-11 
4 ererre  1 2015-03-19 
5 eeeerer 0 2015-03-03
```

Here is the table, - this is query I am adding to get the result. I want the result from the table where date should not be expired if the status is set to 1 and no condition if the status is zero. So it should display. So I made the query like this

```
select * from sample where status='1' AND date>Now() OR status='0'
```

I am getting the result as like this which is correct

```
3 dfdfgfg 0 2015-03-11
4 ererre 1 2015-03-19
5 eeeerer 0 2015-03-03
```

But I want to add more queries to the same, how i can add more condition to above query?

Comment: what new conditions exactly, the way you add them depends on what they are and what output you expect.

Comment: See I have getting result from this query - select * from sample where status='1' AND date>Now() OR status='0', but I want to use any alternative query to this to make it smaller and also I need to add more condition to same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the old condition and the new one in parenthesis , then use an AND to link them:

```
select * from sample 
 where (status='1' AND date>Now() OR status='0') 
   AND (new condition 1) 
   AND (new condition 2) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE expiry_date > NOW()
```

Comment: I want to add more condition after using select * from sample where status='1' AND date>Now() OR status='0'

Answer (score -1):

Try using Union / Union All which soever suffice your requirement

Sample code with example from your data

```
create table sample(id INT,name CHAR(10),  status INT, date_e DATE);

INSERT INTO sample VALUES(1, 'ddd',1,'2015-03-11');
INSERT INTO sample VALUES(2, 'dddd',1,'2015-03-12');
INSERT INTO sample VALUES(3, 'dfdfgfg',0,'2015-03-11');
INSERT INTO sample VALUES(4, 'ererre',1,'2015-03-19');
INSERT INTO sample VALUES(5, 'eeeerer',0,'2015-03-03');


SELECT * FROM sample;
+------+---------+--------+------------+
| id   | name    | status | date_e     |
+------+---------+--------+------------+
|    1 | ddd     |      1 | 2015-03-11 |
|    2 | dddd    |      1 | 2015-03-12 |
|    3 | dfdfgfg |      0 | 2015-03-11 |
|    4 | ererre  |      1 | 2015-03-19 |
|    5 | eeeerer |      0 | 2015-03-03 |
+------+---------+--------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from sample where status='1' AND date_e>Now()
    -> UNION ALL
    -> select * from sample where status='0';
+------+---------+--------+------------+
| id   | name    | status | date_e     |
+------+---------+--------+------------+
|    4 | ererre  |      1 | 2015-03-19 |
|    3 | dfdfgfg |      0 | 2015-03-11 |
|    5 | eeeerer |      0 | 2015-03-03 |
+------+---------+--------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```